# How to debug app using CoreMIDI on iOS connecting to hardware MIDI device?

Tags: ios, midi, coremidi

It seems to me that real (hardware) (USB-)MIDI devices connected to Mac are not listed when running in the simulator. Is there an option to turn this functionality on?

For a concrete example, using e.g. [MIKMIDI](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI), `MIKMIDIDeviceManager.shared().availableDevices` returns 1 device with no model name or manufacturer, **regardless** of whether an actual physical device is plugged in or not (as shown in Audio MIDI Setup). I had similar results with [MIDIFish](https://github.com/Air-Craft/MIDIFish).

'audio' background mode is enabled in the entitlements file.

On the other hand, I am planning to buy a Lightning-to-USB Camera Adapter for this purpose. However, I am not sure how would I debug such a configuration: If the iPhone's Lightning port is already occupied by the Adapter, how would I connect Xcode/Mac to the iPhone?

Any other idea? How do people typically do this?

Thank You.

Comment: "It seems to me that real (hardware) (USB-)MIDI devices connected to Mac are not listed when running in the simulator" Maybe you should _show_ the code that you think isn't working.

Comment: @matt: okay, I just did that, thanks for pointing out the omission.